# How to find unique rows from table sqlite android?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, distinct-values, unique-values

How can i get the unique rows from a table in sqlite database android

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, I have 5 rows in a table(user_table) like below

| id | name | dcode | tno | dname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | satheesh | A01 | 2 | ABC |
| 2 | mahesh | A01 | 2 | ABC |
| 3 | suresh | A02 | 1 | ABC |
| 4 | naresh | A02 | 1 | ABC |
| 5 | rajesh | A03 | 3 | ABC |

To get unique rows with dcode

```
 @Query("select distinct dCode, tno, dname from user_table")
suspend fun getUniqeList(): List<UserDataModel>?
```

and create UserDataModel class like below

```
data class UserDataModel (
var dCode: String? = null,
var tno: String? = null,
var dname: String? = null,
```

)

it will print only three row like below

| dcode | tno | dname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | 2 | ABC |
| A02 | 1 | ABC |
| A03 | 3 | ABC |